# PB7, PD7 (on ATMega32) won't work when pull ups enabled. Also PC6 and PC7 don't show output

Tags: microcontroller, avr, microprocessor, atmega, avr-gcc

I am making 16*16 keypad(on PORTB and PORTD) with ATMega32 using proteus 6.9 and AVRstudio5.

My problem is PB7 and PD7 won't work when pull ups on those pins are enabled. Here PD7 is output, so no problem here. But PB7 must be pull up enabled for matrix. so this part of code wont work as expected:

```
if (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col8)))
{
    while (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col8))){}
    key+=7;
    return key;
}
```

Next problem:PC6 and PC7 also don't give output in any case. I tried changing SFR and too got no solution.

The full code I am using is:

```
/*
 * keyboard.c
 *
 * Created: 10/15/2011 10:54:24 AM
 *  Author: CMANI
 */ 
#define F_CPU 8000000
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define keyportpin1 PINB
#define keyportpin2 PIND
#define keyport1 PORTB
#define keyport2 PORTD
#define keyportdirection1 DDRB
#define keyportdirection2 DDRD

//#define bit_clear(bit) (!(keyportpin&(1<<bit)))
#define col1 PB0
#define col2 PB1
#define col3 PB2
#define col4 PB3
#define col5 PB4
#define col6 PB5
#define col7 PB6
#define col8 PB7


int keyboard(void)
{
    keyportdirection1=0x00;
    keyportdirection2=0xFF;
    keyport1=0xFF;
    int key=1;
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {

        keyport2=0xFF;
        keyport2&=~(0x01<<i);

        if (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col1)))
        {


            while (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col1)))
            {}
            return key;

        }

        if (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col2)))
        {

            while (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col2)))
            {}
            key+=1;
            return key;
        }
        if (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col3)))
        {

            while (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col3)))
            {}
            key+=2;
            return key;
        }
        if (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col4)))
        {

            while (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col4)))
            {}
            key+=3;
            return key;
        }
        if (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col5)))
        {

            while (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col5)))
            {}
            key+=4;
        return key;
        }
        if (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col6)))
        {

            while (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col6)))
            {}
            key+=5;
            return key;
        }
        if (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col7)))
        {

            while (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col7)))
            {}
            key+=6;
            return key;
        } 

        if (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col8)))
        {


            while (!(keyportpin1&(1<<col8)))
            {}
            key+=7;
            return key;
        }

        key+=8;
        }
        return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the *Alternate Functions of Port B/C* section in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc2503.pdf). It shows that for Port C

> TOSC2 – Port C, Bit 7 TOSC2, Timer Oscillator pin 2: When the AS2 bit
>   in ASSR is set (one) to enable asynchronous clocking of
>   Timer/Counter2, pin PC7 is disconnected from the port, and becomes the
>   inverting output of the Oscillator amplifier. In this mode, a Crystal
>   Oscillator is connected to this pin, and the pin can not be used as an
>   I/O pin.
>
> TOSC1 – Port C, Bit 6 TOSC1, Timer Oscillator pin 1: When
>   the AS2 bit in ASSR is set (one) to enable asynchronous clocking of
>   Timer/Counter2, pin PC6 is disconnected from the port, and becomes the
>   input of the inverting Oscillator amplifier. In this mode, a Crystal
>   Oscillator is connected to this pin, and the pin can not be used as an
>   I/O pin

Which is likely why you can't output on those pins. There are similar sections for other ports, and a table that shows exactly which signals can override each pin (eg *Overriding Signals for Alternate Functions in PB7..PB4*).

Take a look through those entries, then if you're still having trouble post your full program including initialisation code.

Comment: Ya I set ASSR bit to zero but too the problem is same. There is no any output on PC7 and PC6.

Comment: My main.c is http://pastebin.com/aDcfuKT0
 and keyboard.c is http://pastebin.com/FzX1P0yx
I kept PB7 scanning inside comment coz the code works great without PB7. But using PB7 seems the code to be working like hell.

Comment: I am not using PORTC pins but while testing, PC6 and PC7 doesn't show output. 3 pins of PORTC are used for LCD control lines.Other pins are required for external control.
My LCD.c is http://pastebin.com/DfGd8hgb

Comment: where is "initialise()" defined?

Comment: And there I wrote a mistake on question, my keyboard is 8*8 matrix for 64 keys.

Comment: Its in LCD.c
called from main.c

Comment: PB7 is shared with the SCK line when using SPI, are you using SPI to communicate with your LCD?

Comment: No I am not using SPI. Those other pins are also used for SPI but they worked well. Do SPI automatically enable when using PB7 used as pull up enabled input? LCD.c is  http://pastebin.com/DfGd8hgb

Comment: No, I wouldn't think so. I would look next at hardware problems and shorts. Try disconnecting the matrix and see if the pullups still don't work. Check for shorts with a multimeter, etc.

Comment: I am doing it in proteus6.9 with code on AVRSTUDIO5. Circuit without PB7 work very well. But I need all 64 keys.

Comment: how could I upload my circuit here? Its in proteus and is .DSN file.

Comment: you can attach images to posts and answers, but more likely is a short on your board or a faulty switch

Comment: Image of circuit is attached as:
https://picasaweb.google.com/100550912715448944468/October162011

Comment: Sorry - I didn't realise you were emulating the circuit. Have you tried swapping PB7 for another port/pin? I would suggest you email Proteus support to see if they can shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Ok peter, thank you very much for your support.I will do as you suggested.